# Where do I find sacrifice?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a level 45 Witch Doctor in Diablo 3, and I haven't played in over a year. Maybe even two, it's been a loooong time. I distinctly remember a cool strategy back then was to sacrifice your zombie dogs, but for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out how to do it now. The Diablo 3 website shows it to be available at level 13, yet I can't find the spell. Where do I find Sacrifice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the Terror tab of skills. The middle one.
[image]

Comment: If you don't see arrows to the right and left of skills, then you can only assign skills from a specific category to a certain button. Button for Terror is [2]. Go to Options -> Gameplay and enable Elective Mode to be a first-class citizen again :-)

Comment: If not for this comment, I never would have solved my problem, this is just as much of an answer as the answer

Comment: Honestly you shouldn't play WITHOUT elective mode on. There are so many builds that require you to assign skills to certain slots that would otherwise be impossible.

Comment: Completely agree with @ChaseC, enabling elective mode is the first thing everyone should do when starting Diablo 3 for the first time.